# Como verificar se uma URL foi bem sucedida em QML?

Tags: qt, qml, uri

Em QML, eu posso executar uma URL externa utilizando:

```
Qt.openUrlExternally(url);
```

Com isso, posso, por exemplo, mandar abrir o app do Facebook em um determinado perfil:

```
var test = Qt.openUrlExternally('fb://profile/###########');
```

No entanto, se o app do Facebook não estiver instalado a URL falhará, mas a função `Qt.openUrlExternally()` continuará retornando `true`. Nesse caso, se eu puder verificar que a chamada falhou eu poderia abrir o Facebook pelo navegador ao invés do app.

A minha dúvida é: como faço para verificar se um *URI scheme* é válido em Qt \ QML?

Comment: Não conseguiu nenhuma solução?

Comment: @bigown Aparentemente, o problema era na implementação da função `openUrlExternally`. Na última versão do Qt eles corrigiram isso (me refiro a implementação para Android). No entanto, para alguns casos específicos não tem como verificar só com o retorno da função. Daí é melhor implementar na parte nativa do código mesmo.

Comment: Acha que consegue por uma resposta mesmo com ressalvas?

Comment: Posso fazer, sim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema na verdade era um erro de implementação da versão Android do Qt (que era que eu estava utilizando).

Quando a função `Qt.openUrlExternally(url)` era chamada, na parte nativa do código a seguinte função era chamada (em QtNative.java):

```
public static void openURL(String url)
{
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    activity().startActivity(intent);
}
```

Ou seja, ela não tratava os possíveis erros e `Qt.openUrlExternally(url)` sempre retornava true.

Com a correção da implementação a função `openURL(String url)` ficou assim:

```
public static boolean openURL(String url)
{
    boolean ok = true;

    try {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        activity().startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        ok = false;
    }

    return ok;
}
```

Corrigindo o problema que eu estava tendo.

Referência do [QTBUG-34716](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/commit/4946ed049608251cf750a6250b4c94cda1c2e707).